# High-Low Order 32 bit word for Addition

Tags: assembly, mips32

I'm studying Assembly MIPS32 and I learnt that for multiplications I have to use `mult rs rt` and that if `rs` and `rt` are both 32bit long I will have a 64bit answer and I'll have to cache it using `mfhi` and `mflo`. But when I'm working with `add rd, rs, rt` and in the case where `rs` and `rt` were both the higher 32bit number (and the sum of both would be a 64bit number for sure) how should I store the 64bit number in a 32bit rd register? Is there a way or both `rs` and `rt` have a maximum of 16bit input while using `add`?

Comment: It's your job to handle overflows. Other architectures provide a carry flag for you, mips doesn't. You just have to check whether the sum is less than one of the inputs, and in that case produce a carry. You can of course mask or range-check inputs to ensure no overflows happen.

Comment: Okay thank you! I had this doubt and had to clarify

Comment: BTW, when you add two unsigned 32b numbers, the result must fit into 33 bits (64b is a bit overkill). So you are losing only the most significant bit in case of overflow. So if you detect overflow, you know the (imaginary) b32 = 1, otherwise b32 = 0, and you can use the remaining 32b result number according to this knowledge. (and most of the SW doesn't even care about 32b overflow, as most of the time the input data are well under that, or when not, it often requires arbitrary precision library anyway). (One exception is file handling 4+GiB are common case today)

Comment: That is helpful too! Thank you!